# How to solve memory leak problem when using opencv.js?

Tags: javascript, python, opencv

I am using opencv.js to process images upload by user but met memory leak problem. I have tried the same code as opencv.js document but still met the problem.

Here is my code:

```html
let land = window.cv.imread("land-show");
let mask = window.cv.imread("mask-show");
let sky = window.cv.imread("sky-show");

window.cv.threshold(
  mask,
  mask,
  parseFloat(trackBarValue),
  parseFloat(trackBarValue),
  window.cv.THRESH_TRUNC
);

let mat = mask.clone();

window.cv.resize(sky, sky, land.size());
window.cv.resize(mask, mask, land.size());
sky.convertTo(sky, window.cv.CV_64FC4, 1);
mask.convertTo(mask, window.cv.CV_64FC4, 1 / 255);
land.convertTo(land, window.cv.CV_64FC4, 1);
sky = sky.mul(mask, 1);

window.cv.cvtColor(mat, mat, window.cv.COLOR_RGBA2RGB, 0);
window.cv.bitwise_not(mat, mat)
window.cv.cvtColor(mat, mat, window.cv.COLOR_RGB2RGBA, 0);
mat.convertTo(mat, window.cv.CV_64FC4, 1 / 255);

land = land.mul(mat, 1);
window.cv.add(land, sky, land);
land.convertTo(land, window.cv.CV_8UC4, 1);
window.cv.imshow("output", land);
land.delete();
mask.delete();
sky.delete();
mat.delete();
```

I have use delete() API to free memory used by Mat objects and tried to use some temp object for convert APIs, but the problem still there. How can I solve it?

Memory reach to maximum:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this frees the original sky?

```
sky = sky.mul(mask, 1);
```

Try

```
skyM = sky.mul(mask, 1);
```

And then free them seperatly when you are done

```
sky.delete();
skyM.delete();
```

And the same for land

Comment: Thanks for your helping. I have tried to comment the code line by line and found that the problem is in `sky.convertTo(sky, window.cv.CV_64FC4, 1);` 
The images I chose is quite large (6000x5000px) so it may caused the problem.
Some users also have the same problems when handle large images too.
[opencv repo issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17034)

Comment: The garbage collector of opencv.js seems not working as expected also.
[opencv.js issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15060)